# Does the roomba 675 have the same open interface spec and as the roomba create 2?

Tags: irobot-create

I see that the create 2 spec says it is based on the roomba 600 series, but I don't know if they are the same or if I should expect differences.  I want to send it a command to get it to turn around with a raspberry PI.  Bump, Virtual Wall, or whatever else works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Roomba 675 supports the same [Open Interface Spec](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/Files/About/STEM/Create/2018-07-19_iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf) as the [Create 2](https://www.irobot.com/about-irobot/stem/create-2.aspx).  You won't get the custom faceplate with mounting hole locations.  But you can download the locations [here](https://www.irobotweb.com/-/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobotCreate2-ScrewBossLocations.pdf).  Remember the serial connector is under the faceplate, then you are good to go.